# Change ViewController within UITabbarController programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I was trying to build an app related to Contacts. In the Storyboard, the entry point is the UITabbarController, and then four UINavigationController which connecting to separated ViewController as below.

[image: storyboard]

In my first tabbarItem, the original ViewController is called contactsVC. I put the codes to detect if the IOS allow this app to access the Contacts in ViewWillAppear. If not allow, I want to put another ViewController to show the privacy policy, and then give the button to show the IOS dialogue.

```
contactsVC.swift:

let privacyViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "accessForContactsViewController") as! AccessForContactsViewController
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([privacyViewController], animated: false)
```

With the codes above, I can embed the privacy view controller in the tabbarController.

in privacyViewController, after button click, I have the codes as below.

```
globalContactStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: {(access, error) -> Void in
            if access {
                    let contactVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contactsViewController")
                    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([contactVC!], animated: false)

                }
            } else {

                let gotoSettingsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gotoSettingsViewController")
                self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([gotoSettingsVC!], animated: false)
            }
        })
```

My purpose is that if access allowed, the app show the original view controller in current tabbar, that is, contactsVC. otherwise, show another view controller. But the codes above doesn't work.

Comment: It is hard to know what you mean by "doesn't work". What did you see happen? Is your `requestAccess` function is being called, is `self.navigationController?` nil? How do you know?

Comment: Thanks for Jonah for your prompt answers. I put the print() and see that the navigationController is not nil.

Comment: I found the reason, with simulator, it takes times to print long log, and then go to the expected view controller. The log is: this application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b5cf45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001052b3deb objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b5ce7d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205

Comment: Error resolved after put the codes (self.navigationController?.setViewControllers) into main thread.  DispatchQueue.main.async {}